How to statically clone an element
According to mdn, querySelectorAll returns a static NodeList. In my example below, clicking the copy checkboxes button will deep copy row0 container of checkboxes to row1 and append it to the DOM. However, it also seems to copy the live state of the checked property of checkboxes. Additionally I noticed the id properties of the new checkboxes were not updated. How can I deep copy an element in its intial state and then update its id properties?
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>static copy test</title>
    <script type="module">
    class CopyClass {
      row0 = document.querySelectorAll('#row0')[0];

      copyRow = () => {
        const row1 = this.row0.cloneNode(true);
        row1.querySelectorAll('#cb0')[0].id = 'cb2';
        row1.querySelectorAll('#cb1')[0].id = 'cb3';
        this.row0.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', row1);
      };

      constructor() {
        document.getElementById('copy').addEventListener('click', this.copyRow);
      }
    }
    new CopyClass();
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <label>check a checkbox and then click button to statically copy</label>

    <button type="button" id="copy">copy checkboxes</button>

    <div id="row0">
      <div id="col0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb0" />
      </div>
      <div id="col1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


You can set the ids dynamically at runtime, like you already do in your code. But then, what do you need the ids for? Do you want to submit a <form> with the checkboxes?

@HeikoTheißen I want to maintain unique ids in the DOM so that I can manipulate them later them from js. In my code above, I tried to update the col0 and col1 ids dynamically but they remained unchanged the browser's Element inspector. However, I can update the new row container's id with row1.id = 'row1'; before inserting it into the DOM.

Never use indexed ids, they're error prone and a nightmare to maintain. Instead of copying from the DOM, create a DocumentFragment of the row, and append a cloned fragment instead. That will tackle the issue of the live checkbox states too.

@Teemu If I don't use unique ids then how else can I reference specific elements in js? I tried const row1 = new DocumentFragment(); row1.append(this.row0.cloneNode(true)) but it has the issues as my original code.

Create the fragment on pageload, before there are any user selections. How to refer the elements depends on how you're going to use them, a small example would help to answer this question.

@Teemu creating the fragment before any user selection should work because cloneNode(true) presumably clones a snapshot of the element's state at the time. Is there any benefit of using DocumentFragment over a regular node like I did in my orginal code?

Yes, it'll work that way. One of the benefits is, that you can append any elements to the fragment (ex. a bunch of tds), no need to worry about the allowed parents (not relevant to your current code, though).
